# Stopped receiving e-mail from a Google Group I've been a manager of for 20 years

Tags: email, google-groups

I've been a manager of this group for 20 years. Suddenly I'm not seeing the e-mails I sent to the group show up in my inbox. They are going to the group because I can see them when I log into groups.google.com but they aren't coming to me. This makes it awkward to keep track of conversations.

This started happening probably yesterday as I did receive some messages I posted 2 days ago.

My account setting is to receive all e-mails.

Any ideas on what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Check Spam box, check filters in GMail, and ask Google for help.

Comment: I don't have spam or other filtering on the web mail interface yet the e-mail doesn't show up there. That was the first thing I checked.

Comment: Posted the question on Google's help lists. No replies there.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the problem was, it went away as mysteriously as it showed up. I'm receiving e-mail again.

Comment: Did you change any settings at all?

Comment: Nope. Changed nothing. Complained to Google about their support and a day later it was fixed.